# javascript arrays in and outside of functions

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript array that I append within a function and call after the function has run (the db information is a call to CouchDB):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  my_array = [];

  view_name = db_name+'/farms_by_name'
  $db.view(view_name, {
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data)
       for (i in data.rows) {
           console.log(data.rows[i]);
           plot_name.push(data.rows[i].value.name);
           my_array.push("0");
           console.log(my_array)
           console.log(my_array.length)
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('Error loading from database: ' + e);
    }
  });

  console.log(my_array);
  console.log(my_array.length);

});
```

Using firebug, I see that within the function the array is appended correctly, for e.g. a single element the console.log returns

```
my_array = ["0"]
my_array.length = 1
```

but the console.log after the function (which appears first in the firebug log) shows:

```
my_array = [ ]
my_array.length = 1
```

and my_array when inspected in the log reveals:

```
[ ]
0              "0"
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me and explain how I should correctly append the array such that I can call the length and loop through it correctly outside of the db success function?

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously it is being executed asyncronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zerkms is right: the variable is being altered inside a success callback function. add a second function in the `$(document).ready` function called -say- logAfterSuccess

```
function logAfterSuccess()
{
    console.log(my_array);
    console.log(my_array.length);
}
```

and simply call that function from within the success callback:

```
success: function()
{
    //code goes here
    logAfterSuccess();
}
```

That should give you the expected result

Comment: OK, so then if I have multiple polls of the database using Ajax, with my main javascript code relying on each query returning a success status, then I'll need to nest the functions within each other....

Comment: (I mean each query returning a success, but only after the previous success)

Comment: Not really, you could set the `async` option to false, making the script execution wait for a the respons

Answer (score 0):

The last two `console.log` will always return [] and 0 because you are checking the array outside of the callback function, if you move the check to inside the callback function you should get your desired results.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  my_array = [];

  view_name = db_name+'/farms_by_name'
  $db.view(view_name, {
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data)
       for (i in data.rows) {
           console.log(data.rows[i]);
           plot_name.push(data.rows[i].value.name);
           my_array.push("0");
           console.log(my_array);
           console.log(my_array.length);
        }
        afterArrayPopulated(my_array);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('Error loading from database: ' + e);
    }
  });
});

function afterArrayPopulated(arr){
  console.log(arr)
  console.log(arr.length)
}
```

Comment: the variable is declared in the $(document).ready function, the issue isn't the scope as such, rather than the asynchronous behaviour of the `success` callback function

Comment: I would also place the `my_array` variable outside of the `$(document).ready` function

Comment: There is no need to pass `my_array` to the `afterArrayPopulated` function, as it will have access to `my_array` directly. PS: it's considered bad manners to take suggestions others made and not crediting them for it, like you obviously did.

Comment: There is no need to pass `my_array` to the function as `my_array` is in the global scope, however to make this function reusable I would pass an array to the function thus allow you to use any variable names you want, as for taking others suggestions I do not feel I have as I commented on my own code prior to seeing your comment.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you mean my code, if you had noticed the time, you would have seen that my answer was prior to yours, so to refer to your comment, why are you making suggestions that I have already produced answers for?

Comment: I have noticed the time, but I made my first comment after I answered this question. The answer I saw then didn't have a code example then, made no mention of a second function, nor did it deal with the asynchronous behaviour of a success function, while my answer did. I figured you made an edit after that, if not: I apologize.